# Excel - Four returnable values, given two crieteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need excel to return one of four possible values given two criteria.  The two criteria are:

- Is the value in cell A1 >= to 10 OR A1 < 10 (two possibilities)

and

- Is the value in cell B1 > 35% OR B1 <= 35% (two possibilities)

There are four possible outcomes for these criteria.  What kind of formula can I use to handle this situation?

Comment: What are you returning? (TT, TF, FT, FF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work -

```
=IF(A1<10,IF(B1>.35,"FT","FF"),IF(B1>.35,"TT","TF"))
```

So first it checks A1 for less than 10, which determines the first letter `F/T`

Then it checks B1, already having had determined the first letter, to determine the second letter `F/T`.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I don't quite understand the logic behind this one, though.  How exactly does this formula work to desplay the two different letter?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joe It displays what I've told it to display, what's in the quotation marks. You can change that to display anything. I chose T and F for simplicity.

Comment: @joe for instance `=IF(A1<10,IF(B1>0.35,"A less than 10 and B greater than 35%","A less than 10 and B less than 35%"),IF(B1>0.35,"A greater than 10 and B greater than 35%","A greater than 10 but B less than 35%"))` also works.

Comment: haha thanks.  You're absolutely right, it showed you exactly what you told it to.  I don't know why I didn't grasp that.  Thanks again for your help!